# Need the number part, when using response.css in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Need the get the Product name and Price from this page "**http://www.fabfurnish.com/Koryo-KLE40DLBH1-39-inches-HD-Ready-LED-TV-Black-294567.html**". I get the Product Name but didnot get the price.

```
item["Product_Name"] = response.css("#product_name::text").extract()[0]
item["Price"] = response.xpath("#price_box::text").extract()[0]
```

So the Output should be : 
Product Name : Koryo KLE40DLBH1 39 inches HD Ready LED TV Black (this I Get)
Price : 22,990 (this I dont Get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For price, you are using a CSS selector in an `.xpath()` call, which expects an XPath expression. Running this triggers an exception which was probably showing in your logs.

So change `.xpath()` to `.css()` for the price value:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.fabfurnish.com/Koryo-KLE40DLBH1-39-inches-HD-Ready-LED-TV-Black-294567.html
2016-12-15 11:25:01 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.2 started (bot: scrapybot)

>>> response.css("#product_name::text").extract()
[u'Koryo KLE40DLBH1 39 inches HD Ready LED TV Black']
>>> response.css("#product_name::text").extract_first()
u'Koryo KLE40DLBH1 39 inches HD Ready LED TV Black'


>>> response.xpath("#price_box::text").extract()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 115, in xpath
    return self.selector.xpath(query)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 207, in xpath
    six.reraise(ValueError, ValueError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 203, in xpath
    **kwargs)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1587, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57924)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:167085)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:166044)
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in #price_box::text
>>> response.css("#price_box::text").extract()[0]
u'26,990'
>>> response.css("#price_box::text").extract_first()
u'26,990'
```

Note the use of `.extract_first()` which is usually safer than `.extract()[0]` (which breaks when there's no result for a selector)